# Несколько материалов для одного шрифта Text mesh pro

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-editor

У меня есть на сцене два текста (TMPro) у них один шрифт, но мне нужно как-то изменить Тени, Осветления и т.д. у другого текста, почему-то юнити решила, что это тексты будут иметь одинаковый материал, и при изменения то ли материала то ли его параметров, изменения будут наблюдаться у двух текстов. Как этого можно избежать?

Answer (score 0):

Ответ нашелся случайно. Я просто скопировал стандартный материал этого шрифта, и просто переименовал, в итоге в списке появилось два материала, второй же я мог изменять не изменяя первый.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете нажать на уже настроенном материале правой кнопкой и выбрать там **Create Material Preset**. Это создаст новый материал со свойствами, которые вы настроили. Дальше вы можете ввести имя, но я заметил, что выбрать для текстфилдов можно только тот материал, который начинается на **имя шрифта SDF**.

[image]